# How to get registry value using path?

Tags: c#

```
public string Read(string KeyName)
{
        RegistryKey oldkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Example"); 
        if (oldkey == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return txtkey.Text = oldkey.GetValue("Name").ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Well whatever else you do, what you are doing in that catch is a total nono. should be removed, or throw new MyRegistryException("Some text", ex);

Answer (score 1):

when you call `Registry.CurrentUser` it is pointed to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` , give path relative to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

you don't  need to include `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in your path string

for example :

```
public string Read()
{
    RegistryKey oldkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes");
    return oldkey != null ? oldkey.GetValue("CurrentTheme").ToString() : null;
}
```